# Typescript: Interface Union <Interface1 | Interface2>

Tags: typescript

I have the following interfaces that are mimicking the data structure returned by the  API:

```js
interface IVehicle {
  color: string;
  wheels: number;
  brand: string;
}

interface IHouse {
  color: string;
  bedrooms: number;
  bathrooms: number;
}
```

The API responses returns a list such as `[{Car1}, {Car2}, {Car3}, {House1}]` so the logical thing to do when declaring a type for that data structure is to use `<IVehicle | IHouse>`; however, when I try to access values in one object where the key does not exist in the other, Typescript throws a error.

```js
class MyClass extends Record({
  apiResponse: Array<IVehicle | IHouse>(),
}) {

  apiResponse.map((house) => house.bedrooms) 
  //                               ^^^^^^^^
  // Property 'bedrooms' does not exist on type 'IVehicle | IHouse'.

}
```

I cannot change the API response. How can I declare such a type in Typescript?

Comment: It should just be `IVehicle | IHouse`. Also, you'll need to do `if ("bedrooms" in house)` or similar so typescript can infer the type.

Comment: Why did you write `<` and `>`?

Comment: check out type predicates https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates

Comment: Sorry, since the response is an array, I use `Array<Type>` signature. I updated the question